# How to remove multiple duplicate words (language names) from an environment variable string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have now this output on running `echo %subsnew%`:

```
English English Arabic Danish Dutch Finnish French German Hindi Norwegian Swedish Turkish English Dutch French German English French German
```

How can remove the duplicates in the variable `subsnew`?

I need the output:

```
English Arabic Danish Dutch Finnish French German Hindi Norwegian Swedish Turkish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a single loop with only 2 statements. The current element is deleted from the collection (which is the tricky part, deleting a variable substring from a string using parameter expansion); if the collection does not change, the element was not yet included and is added then.

```
@echo off
REM input is a string with names
REM return a string with unique names
REM 5:00:06 PM Friday 24/11/2017

if not defined subsnew set "subsnew=English English Arabic Danish Dutch Finnish French German Hindi Norwegian Swedish Turkish English Dutch French German English French German"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM collection may not be empty
set "collection= "
for %%a in (%subsnew%) do (
    REM remove the current name from the collection
    set "test=!collection:%%a=!"
    REM if the collection has not changed, name was missing so it is added now
    if !test!==!collection! set "collection=!collection! %%a"
)
REM remove the leading 2 spaces
set collection=!collection:~2!

echo final string is ^>%collection%^<
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is also very smart and keeps the order of the language strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
rem Define the languages for testing removing duplicates if not already defined.

if not defined set "subsnew=English English Arabic Danish Dutch Finnish French German Hindi Norwegian Swedish Turkish English Dutch French German English French German"

rem Create a local environment for removing the duplicates with enabled
rem command extensions needed for command FOR /F and for command SET with
rem using syntax "variable=value" and enabled delayed environment variable
rem expansion required for rebuilding the language list without duplicates.

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create for each language an environment variable starting with LANG_
rem and name of the language with value 1. The value is not important.

for %%I in (%subsnew%) do set "LANG_%%I=1"

rem Delete the environment variable subsnew.

set "subsnew="

rem Run command SET with argument LANG_ to get listed alphabetically sorted
rem all environment variables starting with LANG_ line by line in format
rem variable=value, e.g. LANG_English=1, LANG_Finnish=1, ...

rem Command FOR executes the command in a separate command process started
rem with cmd.exe /C in background and captures all lines output to handle
rem STDOUT for processing them next line by line.

rem Each line is split up into substrings using underscore and equal sign
rem as string delimiters. The first string is always LANG which is of no
rem interest. The third string is always 1 which is the value of each
rem LANG_* environment variable after the equal sign which is also of no
rem interest. Therefore only the second string being the language string
rem is processed further by assigning it to loop variable I.

rem The environment variable subsnew is rebuild with the language strings.
rem Delayed environment variable expansion is needed as the help output on
rem running in a command prompt window the command SET /? explains on a very
rem similar example to the command line below.

for /F "tokens=2 delims=_=" %%I in ('set LANG_') do set "subsnew=!subsnew! %%I"

rem Restore previous environment which means discarding all environment
rem variables defined and modified after command SETLOCAL above.

rem But the new value of environment variable subsnew is needed in previous
rem environment. So subsnew must be defined again in previous environment
rem with the current value of subsnew in current environment without the
rem space at begin which is done with the command line below.

endlocal & set "subsnew=%subsnew:~1%"

rem Output value of environment variable subsnew with the languages
rem sorted alphabetically and duplicate language strings removed.

echo %subsnew%
pause
```

Please note that this method works only for language strings not containing a space character in language string itself. But it looks like this is no problem here.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Admireable for providing all the comments and help pointers! object creation for filtering was my 1st idea as well, albeit with files. Which is slow and may be cumbersome because of permissions etc. like @Compo then posted. Better keep all in memory instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar idea to that provided by Mofi except it should be a little quicker and the order of the unique variable values should be maintained.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "subsnew=English English Arabic Danish Dutch Finnish French German Hindi Norwegian Swedish Turkish English Dutch French German English French German"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "tmpExt=.$%RANDOM%"
Set "tmpVar="
For %%A In (%subsnew%) Do If Not Exist "%%A%tmpExt%" (Break>"%%A%tmpExt%"
    Set "tmpVar=!tmpVar! %%A")
Del/Q "*%tmpExt%"
EndLocal&Set "subsnew=%tmpVar:~1%
Echo %subsnew%
Pause
```

*The first two and last two lines are for illustration purposes, only the lines between those need pasting into your existing script.*

Comment: That's also an interesting solution and indeed very fast although files are temporarily created and deleted without really writing to hard disk thanks to file caching. In my tests with using Process Monitor to measure the completion time the fastest solution is the one posted by [user1016274](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016274/user1016274) (with suggested optimization). My solution with no comments requiring an additional execution of `cmd.exe` and this solution vary a bit in execution time depending on file system access time, but are between 165 ms and 245 ms in my tests on my machine.